# Gtag Command ignored. Plugin "ec" has already been required on tracker

Tags: google-analytics, gtag.js

I writing the code to track Enhanced E-commerce with the gtag library. The impression of products hit sent when the page load and on clicking the Add to Cart button I sent add_to_cart event. But it gives me this error

`analytics_debug.js:23 Command ignored. Plugin "ec" has already been required on tracker`.

Here is my code

```
gtag("event", "add_to_cart", {
              "items": [
                {
                  "id": "2",
                  "name": "Hoodie",
                  "category": "cloth",
                  "quantity": "2",
                  "price": "16"
                }
              ]
            });
```

Comment: That's not an error, that is a notice. You can just as well ignore it.

Comment: This is an error. Hits are not tracked on Google Analytics if the error message occurs.

Comment: make sure you've enabled enhanced ecommence in your view settings https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6032539

Comment: This is not an error. This merely tells you that GA will not bother to download the e-commerce plugin a second time. This might be caused by some other error in your page, but it is in itself not the problem.